# C++ vector subscript out of range only with non-empty vector

Tags: c++

in the below mentioned code's "insert" function, I'm getting the error vector subscript out of range":

```
// this acts as the vertex of graph
typedef struct node
{
    string name;    // stores the unique name of the vertex
    int value;      // stores the integer data saved in the vertex
} node;

class graph
{
private:
    // 2D vector to store the adjencey list of the graph
    vector< vector<node> > adjList;

public:
    graph()
    {
        adjList.resize(0);
    }

    // function to insert a vertex in graph.
    //  'nName' : unique name of vertex;
    //  'nValue': int data stored in vertex;
    //  'neighbours': string vector containing names of all neighbours
    void insert(string nName, int nValue, vector<string> neighbours)
    {
        int i= adjList.size();
        adjList.resize(i + 1);
        adjList[i].resize( neighbours.size() + 1);

        adjList[i][0].name = nName;
        adjList[i][0].value = nValue;

        string temp;
        for(int nTrav=0, lTrav=1, size=neighbours.size(); nTrav<size; ++nTrav, ++lTrav)
        {
            temp=neighbours[nTrav];

            int j=0;
            for(; j<adjList.size() || adjList[j][0].name != temp; ++j);

            if(j==adjList.size())
            {
                cout << "\nName not present. Element not inserted";
                return;
            }

            adjList[i][lTrav].name = adjList[j][0].name;
            adjList[i][lTrav].value = adjList[j][0].value;

        }
    }
};
```

When the passed string vector 'neighbour' is empty, then the code works properly, but when the vector has some elements, then it gives the specified error.

OS: Windows 8
IDE: Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Why do `vector.resize(size + 1)` instead of `vector.push_back(...)` or `vector.emplace_back`?

Comment: Also, _where_ do you get the subscription error? Have you tried running in a debugger?

Comment: I'm still somewhat taken back by the `resize(0)` in the constructor... apparently *just in case* the standard library threw some random vectors into `adjList` based on some super secret RNG on default-construction?

Comment: I get the error in the line:

    for(; j<adjList.size() || adjList[j][0].name != temp; ++j);

Comment: `typedef struct foo foo;` sounds like the way to declare struct in C. In C++, you can just write `struct foo`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm not getting how do I push back in the 2D vector. Should i create a 1D vector and push it in adjList?

Comment: Why not? Doing e.g. `adjList.push_back(std::vector<node>());` should work fine.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, but I don't like doing things that way; it doesn't FEEL elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from what Joachim comments about `vector.push_back(...)`, you should change the second loop to:

```
for(; j<adjList.size() && adjList[j][0].name != temp; ++j)
```

Replace the OR with AND. You have to be SURE that the `j<adjList.size()` condition is met before evaluating its content. Otherwise, due to lazy evaluation, you will actually only evaluate `adjList[j][0].name != temp` when `j<adjList.size()` returns false. This is, when you are already out of bounds.

Comment: PD: Sorry about multiple edits... I think I got what I intended to say right this time :P